# What do “like”, “heart”, etc. mean?

Tags: communication

I’ve been given Microsoft Teams to communicate with colleagues in a business environment. The text chat includes a [reaction feature](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/like-or-react-to-messages-a8e6060a-56d7-4173-8ed9-277f8640d8e9). The six icons are:

1. A hand with thumb up, labeled “like”;
2. A red heart, labeled “heart”;
3. A face depicting and labeled “laugh”;
4. A face depicting and labeled “surprised”;
5. A face depicting and labeled “sad”; and
6. A face depicting and labeled “angry”.

I’m unsure when it would be appropriate to use some of these reactions. They seem to be poorly adapted to work-related communication, which is odd considering the business-oriented nature of the software. Microsoft doesn’t offer a description of their uses.

The most common reaction I find the need to express is “I agree with this statement.” Is “like” synonymous with agreement?

The next most common reaction I find the need to express is “I don’t know the answer or have a solution.” None of the reactions seem applicable.

I’m reluctant to use “heart” for fear that it could be interpreted as flirting. Is this fear justified?

I can think of two ways that the four facial expressions could be interpreted:

1. This message makes me, the reader, feel this emotion, e.g. “sad” applied to “John will be leaving our group after this month”; or
2. I am characterizing the subject of the message, e.g. “sad” applied to “Client X was such a gullible up-sell”.

Comment: Have you considered just not using them?

Comment: @Helena Yes, but the software is marketed for business use, so I presume the included features are applicable.

Comment: How your team chooses to use them is up to your team. For example, we use the "thumbs up" symbol to indicate I acknowledge or agree with your message. We use the "laugh" when we think something is funny. We don't use the others. A different team might use them differently or not at all. You wouldn't write in Italian if the people on your team only understand German. It's the same way with emoji; if it's not obvious what your meaning is from the context, use a language your team understands instead of a hieroglyph they could misconstrue.

Comment: I'm not understanding the downvotes, this is a sensible question for someone that doesn't have much experience with "reacting" in different software like Teams/Slack/Discord.

Comment: How are your colleagues using these reactions?

Comment: @sf02 “like” is the only reaction that’s getting regular use. There’s no company policy, and the group’s former chat experience is with reply-all email chains.

Comment: "Yes, but the software is marketed for business use, so I presume the included features are applicable." No, not everyone uses the same language when communicating. Even within a single company, a 20 year old salesman is not going to write messages like the 50 year old CEO. My point being. Follow the lead of the colleagues you respect. And if you don't know what something means, don't use it. And you're right, don't use the heart emoji at all unless the context makes is super obvious that you're not flirting.

Comment: While the red heart is commonly labeled "love" it's use in this context would not be interpreted as flirting, but rather very strong agreement.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk in their case this might be true. Seems like they are working in a rather strict environment. But in my company for example a heart is just a really big like. You would heart when a project is finished or even just for support. Like "sending you love" when someone is really sick or something along those lines. 
It is a more open environment and you can even tell colleagues they are looking good without someone thinking it is flirting. When someone dresses up for a client for example.

Answer (score 6):

These are Emoji's, and they're not specific to Teams. If you don't know what they mean you can find out by searching online. There are many Emoji dictionaries and glossaries available.

If you don't know when it's appropriate to use them then don't use them. If you see one and don't know what it means then look it up online.

Teams has the ability to include Emoji's, GIF's, etc. in messages. That doesn't mean you have to use them. If you don't want to use them then don't.

Comment: The emojis are ambiguous and up to the user for interpretation. If you don't know what someone's reaction meant, ask the person who made it, as they are likely the only person who knows for sure.

Comment: @SethR they are no more ambiguous than language.

Comment: "If you don't want to use them then don't" => this 100%. These are optional features. If you don't feel comfortable using them, just ignore them and just stick to writing text messages. There's nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 6):

It will entirely depend on your workplace. My workplace uses Slack which has an even wider selection of emojis and it is common to see people, for instance, using a heart when someone describes a new feature they are particularly keen on, or an angry emoji when someone describes a problem outside their control. But I can easily imagine a more "formal" workplace where people wouldn't use them so much.

Regarding the specific ones you mention, in my experience "like" is synonymous with "agree" and there isn't one you mention that would suit "I don't know". I can't imagine ever using the sad face to describe a "gullible upsell".

If you're unsure, observe what your co-workers do and take your lead from them.